Prove that the increase of the quadratic form implies the increase of the norm
If $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (not essentially the Euclidean norm), and $q(\cdot, \cdot)$is a positive definite quatratic form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, satisfying
$$0\leq q(x,x)\leq\Vert x\Vert^2, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Prove that: for any $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$, s.t. $q(x_1,x_1)\leq q(x_2,x_2)$, then$\Vert x_1\Vert\leq\Vert x_2\Vert$.

I 've known that the previous statement is not correct, and I have a new question now.
Suppose $q, \Vert\cdot\Vert$ are same as above. Consider $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^n s.t.q(x, y)=0. $It's it correct that$\Vert x\Vert\leq\Vert x+y\Vert$ ?

This is not correct. Let us use the Euclidean norm for vectors and the corresponding operator norm for matrices here. Let $P$ be a nonzero matrix, $A=\frac{P^TP}{\|P\|^2}$ and $q(x)=x^TAx=\frac{\|Px\|^2}{\|P\|^2}$. As $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix of norm $1$, we have $0\le q(x)\le\|x\|^2$ for all $x$. Now suppose we can find two vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $\|x_1\|>\|x_2\|$ and $\|Px_1\|<\|Px_2\|$. Then $q(x_1)<q(x_2)$ and the statement that you want to prove is refuted.
For a concrete counterexample, let
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&0\\ -1&2},
\quad A =\frac{P^TP}{\|P\|^2} =\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\pmatrix{1&-1\\ -1&2},
\quad x_1=\pmatrix{1\\ 1},
\quad x_2=\pmatrix{0\\ 1}.
$$
Then $\|x_1\|>\|x_2\|$ but $\|Px_1\|=\sqrt{2}<2=\|Px_2\|$. You may verify that
$$
q(x_1)=x_1^TAx_1=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}<3-\sqrt{5}=x_2^TAx_2=q(x_2).
$$

Your idea is quite useful! And I have an easier counterexample.
Let $n=2$, $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ to be Euclidean norm.  $\forall z=(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, q(z, z)=x^2+\frac{1}{9}y^2$.
Take $x_1=(0, 1), x_2=(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$. Then$q(x_1, x_1)=\frac{1}{9}<q(x_2, x_2)=\frac{1}{4}$, but $\Vert x_1\Vert>\Vert x_2\Vert$.
